# What is this type of geohash?

Tags: hash, geolocation, gis, geocoding, geohashing

I'm trying to get the coordinates of makers of Garmin's ActiveCaptain database and I'm struggling decoding the geohash into "human" coordinates :

| id | poi_type | lastUpdate | name | searchIdentifier | geohash | corresponding coordinates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 38196 | 8 | 1520882974 | Calpe Marina - Real Club Nautico Calpe | -9223372036854775807 | **2331113111314233244** | 38°38.195' N, 0°04.254 |
| 59070 | 8 | 1408502490 | Preveza Marina | -9223372036854775805 | 2331222344133343431 | 38.96021° N, 20.75641° E |
| 17780 | 8 | 1547859601 | Trinidad and Tobago Yacht Club | -9223372036854775765 | 1434321113243422441 | 10°40.672' N, 61°34.105' W |

Here the geoHash should correspond to **38°38.195' N, 0°04.254' E** but passing this 19 character integer through MYSQL ST_LatFromGeoHash function and other geoHash decoder doesn't return the correct coordinates.

Now I'm a bit lost, in which direction should I dig ?

Comment: Direction? By Googling, or by reverse engineering it. Could you feed a coordinate and see the geohash? It seems a strange format. Do you have other examples? All with just digit 1, 2, 3, 4? Often you can divide the string into two (sometime with one of two headers). Then check if it can be number of seconds or of minutes, or a single precision float (base 2 may sometime help)

Comment: I've tried yes. I assumed that there where some hash key, so I divided it. I tried to removed the 1,2,3,4, etc... first digits but no results. I tried to take part of it but as you said, it remove only the precision of the corresponding coordinates.
I found results on the net about hash strings, but not about integers that long.
Another example : 2331222344133343431 should represent 38.96021° N, 20.75641° E

Comment: I only have the data from their API and I don't know how they convert them to coordinates. I tried to search thought their App SDK, but nothing quite relevant about hashes and coordinates. And I cannot play with that much. I take, from the DB, the name of the Place, search it on https://activecaptain.garmin.com to have the coordinates. So if someone know anything about these 19 digits hashes ...